# Can't remove a decimal from a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, replace, etl, data-cleaning

I am trying to remove a decimal from a pandas series.  Currently it's a pandas float.  I will convert it to a string.  Then I want to remove the decimal so I can use this column to merge other data sets. Here is the original output from the code.  The Census Tract Number column is what I am trying to alter.

```
State   County                              Census Tract Number    Life Expectancy
4737    California  Los Angeles County, CA  1011.10                 79.2
4738    California  Los Angeles County, CA  1011.22                 80.0
4739    California  Los Angeles County, CA  1012.10                 82.5
4740    California  Los Angeles County, CA  1012.20                 78.5
4741    California  Los Angeles County, CA  1013.00                 80.0
```

The following code data type was originally a float, I converted it to a string:

```
df202['Census Tract Number'] = df202['Census Tract Number'].astype(str)
```

I got the following error but was able to continue:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

This is what the dataframe morphed into:

```
4737    California  Los Angeles County, CA  1011.1  79.2
4738    California  Los Angeles County, CA  1011.22 80.0
4739    California  Los Angeles County, CA  1012.1  82.5
4740    California  Los Angeles County, CA  1012.2  78.5
4741    California  Los Angeles County, CA  1013.0  80.0
```

I did not want it to cut the zeros at the end, but I continued and tried to remove the decimals:

```
df202['Census Tract Number'] = df202['Census Tract Number'].replace('.', '')
```

The decimals do not remove.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a small regex to extract the census tract number:

```
df['Census Tract Number'] = df['Census Tract Number'].astype(str).str.extract('([0-9]{4})')
```

## edit:

replacing just the dot:

```
df['Census Tract Number'] = df['Census Tract Number'].astype(str).str.replace('.', '')
```

Comment: Hi and thank you.  This answer unfortunately gets rid of the numbers after the decimal and I still need these numbers as they are important identifiers in my data

Comment: @ChuckEPryor Hi, I must have misunderstood the question. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that simply like so:

```
df202['Census Tract Number'] = df202['Census Tract Number'].apply(lambda x : round(x))
print(df.head())
#State   County                              Census Tract Number    Life Expectancy
#4737    California  Los Angeles County, CA  1011                 79.2
#4738    California  Los Angeles County, CA  1011.22              80.0
#4739    California  Los Angeles County, CA  1012                 82.5
#4740    California  Los Angeles County, CA  1012                 78.5
#4741    California  Los Angeles County, CA  1013                 80.0
```

Comment: Hi, thank you...this code does not execute.  Even still I need the numbers after the decimal to stay in tact.

Comment: this code should be used instead of your trials. So, use this instead of `df202['Census Tract Number'] = df202['Census Tract Number'].astype(str)`. And if you still want the Number, then you can create another column easily.